# Камера только в альбомной ориентации

Tags: android, android-camera

Как установить камеру в альбомную ориентацию? Нужно заставить пользователя сфотографировать только в такой ориентации. camera2

Answer (score 0):

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        {   
            p.set("orientation", "portrait");
            p.set("rotation",90);
        }
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {                               
            p.set("orientation", "landscape");          
            p.set("rotation", 90);
        }
```